# iOS Push notification not receive (Firebase Cloud Functions)

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions

everyone! I have problem with receiving notification on iOS. 
The essence of the task is this: when a new record is added to the database, you need to send a notification to all users that match the criteria. On Android everything works correctly, but on iOS - notifications do not receive.

It`s Cloud Functions code:

```
exports.createJob  = functions.firestore
  .document('Jobs/{jobId}')
  .onCreate(event => {
    var jobObject = event.data.data();
    var jobId=jobObject["jobId"]; 
    var jobCategoryId=jobObject["categoryId"];

    var db = admin.firestore(); 

    var nodeToSearch="categoriesMap.".concat(jobCategoryId);
    console.log("new job was added");
    console.log("createJob nodeToSearch".concat(nodeToSearch));

    db.collection('Companies')
        .where(nodeToSearch, '==', true)

        .get()
        .then(function(querySnapshot) {
            querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
                console.log("Company, that suit: ",doc.id, " => ", doc.data().name);
                var registrationToken=doc.data().uidPhone;

                var payload = {
                      data: {
                        notificationType: "NewJobNear",
                        message: "New Job For You",
                        jobId : jobId
                      }
                    };
                    if(registrationToken){
                        console.log("Try to Send to: ",doc.id, " => ", doc.data().name);
                        admin.messaging().sendToDevice(registrationToken, payload)
                              .then(function(response) {
                                // See the MessagingDevicesResponse reference documentation for
                                // the contents of response.
                                console.log("createJob Successfully sent message:", response); 
                                console.log("Success sending ",doc.id, " => ", doc.data().name);
                              })
                              .catch(function(error) {
                                console.log("createJob Error sending message:", error);
                                console.log("Error sending ",doc.id, " => ", doc.data().name);
                            });     
                    }       
            });
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
            console.log("Error getting documents: ", error);
        }); 
    return event.data.ref.set({jobId:event.params.jobId},{merge:true}); 
});
```

Certificates have been added. And when I send to a specific device by token push notification from the console, the notification receives.

I will be very happy with your help.

UPD: 
In the logs to the Functions, a message appears that the notification was successfully sent to the user. This lines:

```
console.log("createJob Successfully sent message:", response);
console.log("Success sending ",doc.id, " => ", doc.data().name);
```

Comment: It looks like you're not waiting for *all* of the promises from all of the async work you're performing.  You're just returning one of them.  Collect them all into an array and return the value of Promise.all() to make sure you wait for all of them.

Comment: @DougStevenson Can you answer in more detail?

Comment: Not sure, but looks like you have two kinds of notifications : data type and notification type. I recently noticed that receiving notification in iOS is easier.  Try using notification instead of data in your payload.

Comment: did you solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same case with you and used a payload of notification messages type instead of data messages type. The problem was fixed.

Firebase Cloud Messaging supports two message type: Notification messages and Data messages. please refer [official document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#notifications_and_data_messages).

```
{
  "message":{
    "token":"bk3RNwTe3H0:CI2k_HHwgIpoDKCIZvvDMExUdFQ3P1...",
    "notification":{
      "title":"Portugal vs. Denmark",
      "body":"great match!"
    }
  }
}
```